# In Waterline save() on an entity is asynchronous but doesn't return a promise

Tags: promise, sails.js, bluebird, waterline

I am creating a Sails.js app using Waterline as an ORM. There is a sequence that creates and entity `Room` and adds two `User` entities immediately with `add()`, and `save()`. This works except that save() does not return a promise as does all other Model operations such as `Room.findOne()...then(()=>{})` because the originating function expects a **promise** in return, I need to manually create a promise to make it work.

Is making a promise manually the best plan? Any other recommendations?

Comment: How do you "manually create a promise"? Please show us that code so we can suggest improvements.

Comment: Have you considered filing a bug report with the library about the inconsistent return value?

Comment: On similar lines, `query()` also doesn't return promise. [This method does not support .exec() or .then(), and it does not return a promise.](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query)

Comment: Isn't query() synchronous?

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/find-one) doesn't say anything about `findOne()` returning a promise, but you can wrap `.save()` in a promise pretty much the same way you would with any other callback-based function:

```
function saveWithPromise(entity) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        entity.save(function (error) {
             if (error) { reject(error); } else { resolve(); }
        });
    });
}
```

To use it:

```
saveWithPromise(myEntity)
    .then(function () { console.log('all done!'); });
```

Comment: This is a great response. If I find the issue comes up multiple times, I will definitely use something like this.

Answer (score 0):

This was my initial solution, but perhaps I need to submit a feature request to add Bluebird support to save().

```
room.participants.add(users);
let roomPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{

      room.save((err) => {
        if(err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        resolve(room);
      });

    });
return roomPromise;
```